# how to merge an attribute in multi-inheritence

Tags: multiple-inheritance, eiffel

Repeatedly inheriting from 2 classes having the same parent, I fall into the classic case of inheriting 2 times of the same attribute. I'd like to merge the 2 attributes into one and tried to do it with an undefine, but it gets me a compile error.
The other solution I see is renaming the attribute from one of both parents, but as I understand each instance of my D class would have an useless attribute which is not what I want...

`Error: Undefine subclause lists name of frozen feature or attribute or 
    C external.
What to do: unless you can change the status of the feature in the parent,
    remove its name from Undefine subclause since it cannot be undefined.`

How to merge 2 attributes from repeatedly inherited classes

```
class A
    serial: STRING

end -- class A

class B

inherit
    A

end -- class B


class C

inherit
    A

end -- class C


class D

inherit
    B
        undefine 
            serial -- error seems to appear here in that case
        end
    C

end -- class D
```

Comment: Class `C` is not used in the example and could be safely removed.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov I was meaning class D inherit B & C, too late to post yesterday ;-) Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's two unrelated attributes (not coming from the same parent) that you want to merge, you should redefine both of them:

```
class A
feature
    serial: STRING
end

class B
feature
    serial: STRING
end

class C
inherit
    A
         redefine
               serial
         end
    B
         redefine
               serial
         end
feature
    serial: STRING
end
```

As you already saw, the compiler will not let you undefine an attribute, even when the goal is to merge it with another attribute.

Comment: Thx Eric! in case of renaming too? It was my case! Thx you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to undefine a feature that is going to be merged with the same version coming from a different inheritance path. In the example, the attribute `serial` is not changed in `B`, `C`, and `D`. Therefore, inheriting from `B` and `C` without any adaptation is OK:

```
class D inherit
    B
    C
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear in my question, I edited it hope I'm more this time

Comment: @Pipo The answer remains the same: just keep the attribute under the same name, it will be merged into the one without an error.

Comment: Eric gave me the reason, my example was not complete as I renamed the attribute into class B! renaming to serial again into D and redefining it gave me the solution!

Comment: @Pipo I would suggest editing the question to reflect the problem you were facing. My answer addresses a completely different issue stated in the original question.

Comment: yes, but then you'll have to edit your answer, so I don't want you having to edit your whole answer, that was the reason I didn't want to edit it